# How to get route param value in resolve in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a resolve defined:

```
export class ItemResolve implements Resolve<number> {
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
    resolve(): Promise<number> {
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap); // EMPTY OBJECT
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));  // NULL
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data);  // EMPTY OBJECT
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.param);  // EMPTY OBJECT
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(0);
        });
    }
}
```

And the route:

```
{
    path: 'items/edit/:id',
    component: ItemeditorComponent,
    resolve: {item: ItemResolve}
}
```

In resolve, i always get empty array, null or undefined values, it does not matter what im trying to use. I tried routeParams, parads, data and every possible variations that was available in google i think..

Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Angular version: 7.2.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route method takes a `ActivatedRouteSnapShot` argument, that you should use:

```
interface Resolve<T> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

In your case

```
export class ItemResolve implements Resolve<number> {

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<number> {
      const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
      return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i got an error: NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!, and i found this: "ActivatedRouteSnapshot is not a provider." so i cannot use it and others said i should use ActivatedRoute and use its snapshot param...

Comment: It's not injected. It parameter of the resolve method.